# React/js onClick on both the Parent div and Child div. Parent always fires

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i got a problem with having onClick on my parent and on its child that triggers which menuSection shows up. And even if i click on the child its the parents section that shows up. How to only trigger the child if that element gets clicked?

```
    <div> onClick={() => props.onClick(MenuSection.Default)} >
          <div <span><InfoIcon /></span> Some info</div>
          <div>More Info</div>
          <div>Even more Info</div>
          <div onClick={() => props.onClick(MenuSection.NotDefault)}><InfoIcon /></div>
    </div>
```

So here is how it looks and its always MenuSection.Default that shows up never MenuSection.NotDefault.

Comment: there is a typo in the 2nd line: `<div <span>`

Comment: you can use `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @BeniaminH oh yeha sorry edited happend when pasting it in only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pass in e in the function and use

> e.stopPropagation();

```
<div onClick={() => props.onClick(MenuSection.Default)} >
      <div <span><InfoIcon /></span> Some info</div>
      <div>More Info</div>
      <div>Even more Info</div>
      <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation();props.onClick(MenuSection.NotDefault)}><InfoIcon /></div>
</div>
```

But I would also move the onClick inline function out of the render method and reference it with "this.nameOfClickMethod", nameOfClickMethod is of course to be named at your choise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()`. It prevents the event from propagating.

```
<div> onClick={() => { props.onClick(MenuSection.Default)} } >
          <div <span><InfoIcon /></span> Some info</div>
          <div>More Info</div>
          <div>Even more Info</div>
          <div onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation();props.onClick(MenuSection.NotDefault)}}><InfoIcon /></div>
    </div>
```